# Using the extra_hosts directive in docker compose, how can I add hosts that are written in a file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For reasons I cannot control, we have a file called `my_hosts` which contains mappings of IP addresses to hostnames, for example:

```
127.0.01        localhost
10.25.28.29     example.com
10.22.33.34     test.com
```

I know there is an [`extra_hosts`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts) directive that allows for hostname mappings to be added manually in the Docker compose file, like this:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
  - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
```

However, I would like to add the mappings inside the `my_hosts` file. The mappings inside the file can change (we could add or delete any mappings).